# Is the amplitude -1 as loud as amplitude 1?

Tags: waveform

I am uncertain about the concept of the sine wave's amplitudes: for a say 1 hz sine wave is the oscillation between loud and silent parts to be thought of as oscillation between amplitudes 1 and -1, in other words is an amplitude of -1 as loud as amplitude 1?

Comment: Amplitude must have a unit, such as a decibel (with an explicit or implied reference). In other words, 1 or -1 what?

Comment: @ToddWilcox  -1 to +1 is the display values such as Audacity use as "full scale".

Comment: Yep, -1 and +1 have the same amplitude.

Comment: @Tetsujin huh. Huh? Not 0 dBFS? Oh wait maybe it’s the signed int sample value scaled to 1 so you don’t have to keep track of 16, 24, and 32 bit values?

Answer (score 1):

> for a say 1 hz sine wave is the oscillation between loud and silent parts

No *loud* and no *silent* parts for **1 Hz** frequency, sorry. You will hear nothing… ;-)

---

The perceived sound is an **oscillation of air** (or water, if you dive into it) – you may imagine air oscillating in the direction to your ear and then from your ear, repeatedly.

It means that the pressure to your eardrum

- progressively increases to reach your **+1** maximum value (in some linear units),
- then progressively decreases to **0** (no pressure),
- continuing decreasing to the value **-1**
  (underpressure for your eardrum, with its maximal value at **-1**).

So +1 and -1 values are both maximum values for the pressure / underpressure to your eardrum, but hardly to say that there are maximum values for the perceived *loudness* of the sound.

During one oscillation of the sine wave (**0** to **+1** to **0** to **-1**) *we don't perceive changes in loudness,* we perceive something as an *average value*.

(Similarly, the needle of a voltmeter plugged into the 230 V / 50 Hz  electric outlet *don't oscillate between **-325 V** and **+325 V*** – it stays at the **230 V** value.)